# Incorporating an image map to mouseover and mouseout issue

Tags: image, dictionary, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to take an image, and when you put your mouse over it a larger image appears with a image map attached to it. You can view it [here](http://clubpenguinmemories.com/Pacman/igloo.html)

Take a look at it. As you can see, when you mouse your image over the cassette tape image it'll switch as it should, however as soon as you put your mouse over the selected areas in the image map the image disappears. I do want the image to switch back to the cassette tape only when you take your mouse off of the image, but not on the href area! How can I correct this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it with jQuery. Instead of swapping the image source, just use two images so you have better control over the events.

Because the first image is the same size as the 2nd one, the image will appear when you mouse over the tape *or* in the area where the menu will appear. If you use an image that's just the size of the tape this won't happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/7tcaE/2/

```
$('#tape').bind('mouseover',function() {
   $('#menu').show();
});
$('#menu').bind('mouseout',function() {
   $('#menu').hide(); 
});
```